# How to implement Redux?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Should I use Redux for all API calls even if the data to be processed is not shared between different components?
Example: A users-list component must retrieve the list of users and display it in the interface. These users are not used outside this component. Does the API call must be implemented with actions/reducers/effects?

Comment: Checkout the sample app https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/README.md to see how it works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on your targets of course. If you want to just try Angular it is not your choose. If you plan that your app will grow - it is not bad idea. Actually, if you will use "module by feature" structure, you can easily add ngrx to your project in the future.

Redux is about state management. Maybe you think it is overkill now. But be sure that your app will grow.You will get more modules, it will be harder to handle everything.

Also, redux adds some structure to your application. I believe that if new guy comes to the team, if team uses redux, new peoples will get on with project easily. Even if they are juniors, let them read about redux/ngrx and they can easy track how data flows in your application. Actually, this is true even if react dev comes to angular team or vice versa. At least for me: me and my colleague can easily discuss problems and solve them successfully but I use Angular and he uses React.

Should you follow the redux process for API calls? Well. Technically you can ignore this. But why? There are a lot of useful tools around Redux. For example redux dev tools. If you use actions to make api calls then you see them in Redux dev tools too. You can see list of actions, payload of actions (what you received from the server), how this action changed your state.

Comment: Thanks.
For the Redux project, do I have to follow the redux process for all my API calls?

Comment: Why not? Redux is about state management. Data, event retrieved from the server is part of state of your app. So why should you ignore this profits? You will have log, you will have clear way of data because of redux.

Comment: I have a lot of API calls and in many cases it's just for building a single component and the data isn't shared with other components. It will be hard to do all this with redux.

Comment: Why you think is it hard? You need some actions, reducer, some effects and selectors. I am not sure it is really hard.

Comment: You need to choose what you want :) it is not problem to store state of this extra component in separate reducer. It's totally OK. If you want something like one way data flow and predictable state management redux is your choice.

Comment: You don't need redux for one way data flow and predictable state management in this instance. Your just using tech words. The same as you would not use a redux pattern to control the active state of a single button on if it's pressed or not.

Comment: @Meeker in what cases do you need redux then? Everything depends on what you want. Redux means everything is stored in one place (single source of truth). It is much more predictable the separated data services.

Comment: Yes you can implement single source of truth without redux yes. Redux provides more. Here you can read everything about it: http://redux.js.org/.

Answer (score 0):

If the data and the logic are all self contained then there is no need to use a redux pattern as it will simply introduce unneeded complexity.

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

Comment: Totally agree with @Meeker. You may think of Redux as an alternative to your project if you are thinking about scaling it in the future. If you're just creating a single component app, I would also recommend not using Redux.

Comment: Yes it's clear. But my question was: In a Redux project, do all API calls must follow the actions / reducers / effects process even for the data not shared between components. I gave an example in the post.
thanks.

Comment: No they do not. In fact it's bad practice if you want components that are shareable and reusable and easy to maintain.

Comment: If the data and the logic are all self contained . Yes it is now. Will your application grow? If yes then after some time your app can get into a mess. If no and there is no target to try redux then it is ok to not use it.

Comment: We are not talking about an application. The question specifically outlines a single self contained components. Your rewriting the use case to justify your answer. https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

Comment: Are you mad about my answer is accepted? Its ok, I don't care much about it. I provided usefull information. I gave different cases. I said it depends on targets. I also provided cases where it will be useful. I also answered initial question about API calls. My answer is full enough.

Comment: I'm simply providing the best responses to the comments and answers as they were given. I apologise if you have become offended.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly What is Redux ?**

> Redux is an application state manager for JavaScript applications, and
>   keeps with the core principles of the Flux-architecture by having a
>   unidirectional data flow in your application. Redux applications have
>   only one global, read-only application state. This state is calculated
>   by "reducing" over a collection or stream of actions that update it in
>   controlled ways.

**Redux In Angular ?**

> Redux state managers have been very well received and have inspired
>   the creation of @ngrx, a set of modules that implement the same way of
>   managing state as well as some of the middleware and tools in the
>   Redux ecosystem. @ngrx was created to be used specifically with
>   Angular and RxJS, as it leans heavily on the observable paradigm. 
>   Both the Components you see above are managed using ngrx store
>   (updated to v4) Advantages of upgrading now we have support for lazy
>   loading directly in ngrx using Featured Module

**Where to Use it ?**

A small scenario will make its use quite clear

> I am hoping you might have used facebook right :P so if you look @ facebook's
>   website you will see multiple components like navbar, left panel,
>   chatbox etc. Ever wondered when a new message is delivered to you all
>   these are updated simultaneously how ? If they went for srevices or
>   Event Emitters they would be engulfed in a sea of spaghetti code.
>   Which even if implemented will be very hard to debug or make changes .
>
> Here comes the use of ngrx state management all the information is
>   stored @ a single place and all the components are identified when the
>   state of the data is changed . A Look this answer from stack overflow
>   will clear the concepts even more Image clear.

**How to implement Redux ?**

There are two choices in Angular one is `ng-redux` and other is `ngrx`. I personally Like ngrx with its vast community and great idea .

You can take a look @ this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx) for a counter application and adding list to Ngrx v4 .

If you want to take a look @ a whole application using the whole ngrx suite implementation take a look at [this git repo](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/FootBallScores) this is deployed at [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/FootBallScores).

This reference to this comes from my [gh-page](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts) where i spread the word of Angular Concepts.